# Output does not print the correct variable addresses

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, printf, conversion-specifier

Despite using `double` as datatype and correct format specifiers the output does not print the correct variable addresses output consists of just zeros

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    double a[5] = { 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0 };
    double *p;
    p = a;
    printf("%lf \n", p);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         printf("%lf \n", p++);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

Comment: You can't use `%lf` to print pointers.  Are you trying to print the pointers themselves, or the pointed-to values?

Comment: You probably want `*p` and `*p++`.

Comment: Also, cast to `(void*)`, if you use `%p`.

Comment: @SteveSummit  thank you so much I understood my mistake I was trying to print the address not value , hence using %d fixed it!

Comment: @SharanyaThambi Okay, but in that case, you want `%p`.  You should not use `%d` to print addresses, and on an increasing number of machines, it won't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with 2 simple changes, described in the comments.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    double a[5]={6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0};
    double *p;
    p=a;
    printf("%p \n",p);       // Changed formatter to %p  to print addresses
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
         printf("%p \n",p++); // Changed formatter to %p to print addresses
    }
}
```

### Output

```
0x7fffdd887250 
0x7fffdd887250 
0x7fffdd887258 
0x7fffdd887260 
0x7fffdd887268 
0x7fffdd887270
```

Comment: `printf("%p \n",p);` --> `printf("%p \n",(void*)p);`

Answer (score 0):

These calls of `printf`

```
printf("%lf \n",p);
```

and

```
printf("%lf \n",p++);
```

invokes undefined behavior because there is used the wrong conversion specifier `"%lf"` (where by the way the length modifier has no effect even when used with object of the type `double`) with pointers.

Either you should use the conversion specifier `%p` like

```
printf("%p \n", ( void * )p);
```

and

```
printf("%p \n", ( void * )p++);
```

Or if you want to output addresses as integers you can include headers `<stdint.h>` and `<inttypes.h>` (the last header already includes the first header and write

#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

//...

```
printf("%" PRIuPTR "\n", ( uintptr_t )p);
```

and

```
printf("%" PRIuPTR "\n", ( uintptr_t )p++);
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main( void )
{
    double a[] = { 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    double *p = a;


    printf( "%p", ( void * )p );
    printf( " <-> %" PRIuPTR "\n", ( uintptr_t )p );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%p", ( void * )p );
        printf( " <-> %" PRIuPTR "\n", ( uintptr_t )p++ );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
00AFFE40 <-> 11533888
00AFFE40 <-> 11533888
00AFFE48 <-> 11533896
00AFFE50 <-> 11533904
00AFFE58 <-> 11533912
00AFFE60 <-> 11533920
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe make the printf of for loop like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
printf("%lf \n",p[i]++);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
0.000000         
6.000000         
7.000000         
8.000000         
9.000000         
10.000000
```